# POST request in loop using threading. Will there be duplicates?

Tags: python, multithreading

Let me start with saying that I've never used threading in Python.
I have a list containing about 8000 dictionaries. It contains data about ingredients, their calories, nutrients etc.

```py
for index in range(len(listOfFilteredFoods)):
    for key in listOfFilteredFoods[index]:
        if(listOfFilteredFoods[index][key] == None):
            listOfFilteredFoods[index][key] = 0.0

    requests.post(url, data=listOfFilteredFoods[index])
```

This loop checks if any field (vitamin A, potassium or other) is equal to None then it just overwrites is with 0.0. Then each dictionary is POSTed to my Django database. **Problem is this 8k list took about 10minutes to complete. If i were to use threads will there be duplicates of same ingredient instances?**

## Edit

The dictionary in question looks like this (abbreviation):

```json
[
 {
  "name": "#1 Ingredient name",
  "calories": 100.0,
  "nutrient#1": 10.0,
  "nutrient#2": 20.0,
 },
 ...
 {
  "name": "#8000 Ingredient name",
  "calories": 100.0,
  "nutrient#1": 10.0,
  "nutrient#2": 20.0,
 }
]
```

Comment: If each POST is run in a discrete thread you will not get duplicates because the reference to your data is different every time. It would help to get a more complete answer if you could show what listOfFilteredFoods looks like. As it stands, your loops look rather strange

Comment: 1. I suggest using async operations (aiohttp) instead of multithreading
2. Answer depends on code receiving the request way more than it does on the one sending the POST request. Without seeing how POSTed data is processed server-side it's hard to tell whether duplicates will happen or no.

Comment: @matszwecja At the moment every POST request for `/api/v1/ingredients/` will be accepted.
@JCaesar I've added the abbreviation of how the list of dictionaries looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I have no way to test this but this pattern of execution is probably what you need.

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

listOfFilteredFoods = [
 {
  "name": "#1 Ingredient name",
  "calories": 100.0,
  "nutrient#1": 10.0,
  "nutrient#2": 20.0,
 },
 {
  "name": "#8000 Ingredient name",
  "calories": 100.0,
  "nutrient#1": 10.0,
  "nutrient#2": 20.0,
 }
]

url = 'myFavouriteURL'

def doPOST(data):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.post(url, data=data).raise_for_status()


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    try:
        for d in listOfFilteredFoods:
            for k in d.keys():
                if d[k] == None:
                    d[k] = 0.0
            executor.submit(doPOST, d)
    finally:
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Comment: Yeah just now I've tried to use `concurrent.futures` but I didn't know that SQLite cant handle so many parallel requests. But thanks for help nevertheless!

Comment: If you're accessing SQLite in a thread you will need to establish a new connection within the thread as SQLite connections are not thread safe

Answer (score -1):

2 points.

1 - If you call this loop more one times (eg: by button action) thread will start again. So yes "will there be duplicates of same ingredient"

2 - If you only put this loop in thread function, no you not "will there be duplicates of same ingredient", because thread will running in "background", but sequential.

Comment: I don't think putting the loops inside a thread makes any sense. Moving the POST to a separate thread would work as would an asyncio approach

Comment: @JCaesar but can you see that put request are in for loop?

Comment: Yes. There are two *for* loops. The POST is within the outer loop although that's probably sub-optimal